# Shell Alias Which Whitespace Cancelling

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, zsh

When creating an alias for a binary tool in a folder that contains a space, the alias is correctly stored, but when the command is called, the space is evaluated as if it isn't properly cancelled.

The binary is viewable in `$PATH`. I ran this from zsh 4.3.11 and bash 3.2.48, both with the same result.

Binary Path

```
~/Test Folder/fooBinary
```

Alias

```
alias foo="`which fooBinary`"
```

This results in

```
foo='~/Test Folder/fooBinary'
```

Now calling this alias results in

```
[shell]: no such file or directory: ~/Test
```

This used to work to escape the spacing from the alias and I didn't bother to check the version of my older shell or I would go find it.

The I did to actually escape the spacing:

```
alias foo="'`which fooBinary`'"
```

My questions:

Why are the spaces evaluated in the quoted alias?
Is there a better way of escaping `which`?

Comment: If `fooBinary` is found by `which`, then `fooBinary` is in your `PATH` and can be invoked as `fooBinary`, without worrying about the full path. The alias `alias foo=fooBinary` should work as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Either because I need to pass arguments or some other issue. When I try it this way I get an error response hence the need for the quote escaping `which`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases have always split on spaces. This is intentional and useful as it allows you to alias arguments, e.g. `alias rm='rm -i'` or `alias commit='git commit -a'`.

If you need to quote an argument programmatically, you can use `printf %q` to add a level of escaping:

```
alias foo="$(printf %q "$(which fooBinary)")"
```